# Unbind a specific function jQuery

Tags: jquery, function, scrolltop, unbind

What I'm trying to do is unbind a specific function, after it has run once. In the code below it's the window scroll.

```
 $(window).scroll(function(){
     if($(window).scrollTop() == viewportheight ){
          $("#landing_page").fadeOut(function() { $(window).scrollTop(0); $(window).unbind("scroll");});
     }
 });
```

Basicly, when the #div fades out, I want it to scrollTop(0). After scrolling top, I need this entire function to unbind.

Is there a way to give this function a specific name, and then call back that name? Because this code works, only it removes all scroll functions. (Wich ofcourse I don't want) I was thinking something like so:

```
 $(window).scroll(function(FUNCTION NAME HERE){
     if($(window).scrollTop() == viewportheight ){
          $("#landing_page").fadeOut(function() { $(window).scrollTop(0); $(window).unbind("FUNCTION NAME HERE");});
     }
 });
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Jefferson, something like...

```
$(window).bind("scroll.myScroll", function(){
     // stuff
  })
```

now, unbind the scroll - I have it a unique identifier just in case you have other window scroll events, you don't want to mess with.

```
$(window).unbind('.myScroll');
```

Comment: Is there posibility to unbind a function created like this: `jQuery.fn.scrollVal = function (jump, type) {...}`? Becuase sth like this doesn't work: `$('#ReleaseVersion').unbind('.scrollVal');`

Answer (score 0):

you can use  **jquery.unbind** function to unbind any particular event for the element

Comment: I've tried unbinding the scrollTop, wich doesn't work. It keeps firing the function.