# How can I view the source code of this "jQuery bind/unbind custom function" feature?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Well, I have already used this "bind & unbind *custom* function" feature from jQuery, from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15106918/unbind-a-specific-function-jquery):

```
$(window).bind("scroll.myScroll", function(){
  // stuff
})
```

And unbind this custom function:

```
$(window).unbind('.myScroll');
```

But when I tried to search the source code of this magic feature, I can't find any reference. I have both tried the official document and unofficial ones from Google.

Is there any way that I can view it? Just want to know how jQuery implement this.

Comment: have you tried to open a un-minified jquery file?

Comment: related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21817397/event-handler-namespace-in-vanilla-javascript

Comment: The question did answer all my confusions. Thanks!